# playerOne.Score += 1; isnt working when my player picks up a item?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so currerntly i am working on a game just uses visual studio using C# but i have a issue where the player picks up a coin but it is not added to the score any reason why this would be.

```
void CheckPlayerOnPickup()
    {
        foreach (Pickups pickup in pickups)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 30);
            Console.Write(pickup.x + " " + pickup.y + " " + playerOne.X + " " + playerOne.Y);
            if (playerOne.X == pickup.x && playerOne.Y == pickup.y)
            {
                if (pickup.mychar == 'O')
                {
                    playerOne.Score += 1;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

happy to supply more code if needed

Comment: When is `CheckPlayerOnPickup` called? Are you sure that `playerOne.Score += 1;` is called - that the condition is true? Why do you need to cycle through all pickups when you should know the pickup from the collision event?

Comment: ive debugged it and the playerOne.score isnt being called i think thats the issue but dont know how to fix it

Comment: If you are debugging it: you have 3 conditions before the +1 is getting called. Check what each value is and compared to what it should be. One quite likely error is the location. Your pickup position will never be exact on the same position as the player

Comment: ah alright how do i go about fixing that

Comment: I don't know your game or how you are currently detecting collision with your item. But the easy way would be just on the OnEnterCollsion event of the pickup to increase the score and delete itself afterwards.

Comment: would that work even though its not in the unity game engine

Comment: That totally depends on the options of whatever system you are using. If it has the capability to detect collision, there should be information about the object it collides with

Comment: Are x and y here floating point numbers, or integers? Usually with floats we'd compare them with some tolerance range.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to compare position with the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
void CheckPlayerOnPickup() {
    float pickupDistance = 1.0f;
    foreach (Pickups pickup in pickups) {
        if (DistanceFrom(playerOne.X, playerOne.Y, pickup.x, pickup.y)  < pickupDistance) {
            if (pickup.mychar == 'O') {
                playerOne.Score += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

float DistanceFrom(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float a = x2 - x1;
    float b = y2 - y1;
    float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    return distance;
}
```

Here, we calculate the distance from the player to the pickup using the Pythagorean theorem; if it is less than the `pickupDistance` threshold, the player can earn a point. Game engines will come with lots of functions for common operations like measuring distance, but if you aren't using a game engine, you either need to write these helper functions yourself, or find a library that includes them.

Note that this approach of comparing position using distance is usually necessary when you have a continuous coordinate system (e.g. coordinates are `float`s or `double`s). If you have a discrete coordinate system (such as on a chessboard) where positions are represented with integers or other discrete values, you should be able to simply perform an equality check.

Put more simply:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 3;
Debug.WriteLine(a == b); //outputs "True"

float x = 3.0f;
float y = 3.00001f;
Debug.WriteLine(x == y); //outputs "False"
```